# or_like not working in codeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to run a query with multiple like combined using or in mysql query from code Igniter.
I have following code for that purpose.

```
$this->db->group_start();
                    foreach ($active['result'] as $outcode) {
                        $this->db->or_like('postcode',$outcode['outcode']);

                    }
                    $this->db->group_end();
```

It does create the query as expected apart from the problem that it contains **ESCAPE '!'** between each part.
here is query printed.

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl_service_providers` WHERE `is_active` >= 1 AND ( `postcode` LIKE '%SS13%' ESCAPE '!' OR `postcode` LIKE '%SS14%' ESCAPE '!')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `$this->db->escape_like_str()`

```
$this->db->or_like('postcode', $this->db->escape_like_str($outcode['outcode']));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this :

```
 $this->db->group_start();
 foreach ($active['result'] as $k=>$outcode)
 {
   if($k == 0)
    {
        $this->db->like('postcode',$outcode['outcode']);
    }
    else
    {
       $this->db->or_like('postcode',$outcode['outcode']);
    }
 }
 $this->db->group_end();
```

Comment: what is the purpose of $K==0?

Comment: this will never be the case in my example as the $results contain string data

Comment: the purpose of that counter is because the first element of your query must be with like and the other with or like.How can it be a string if you make a foreach loop?